# How do I send XML using ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, xml, ajax, web-services

**Update 2**

After carefully reading the doc about ajax and the data property [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) it says that **"Object must be Key/Value pairs"**, so therefore I can not just pass any object but must wrapp it in some kind of associative array, or JSON, which can be something like this {theResp:leXmlDoc}, so therefore **contentType:"XML"** does really do anything am I correct?

Hi I would like to send data via AJAX to my ASMX webservice. By that I mean want to send data with the contentType: "application/xml", "text/xml" or "xml". I cannot seem to find the right way to format my XML so that my AJAX can work. If I wrap it inside a JSON then I am able to send it without any problem. So I was wondering is there a specific way I am suppose to form my XML? Here is m AJAX: A few notes I tries passing leXmlDoc as a XMl source string and as an Dom Document object.

```
function sendToServer(leXmlDoc) {
  console.log($.isXmlDoc(leXmlDoc)); //Here I check if leXmlDoc is an XML Document, I   
  also tries using jsut the XML source string
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',       
    processData: false, //I also tried setting it to true
    contentType: "xml", //I also tried application/xml, and text/xml
    dataType: "xml",
    url: "/Webservices/TransferXmlData.asmx/SendingXmlToServer",              
    data: leXmlDoc, 
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("there is a problem sending the XML");
    }
  });
};
```

My webservice, I know this works because when I send a JSON it return me the data I sent it. Unless it needs to be different to accept XML.

```
  <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    Public Function SendingXmlToServer(ByVal theResp As String) As String           
        Return theREsp
    End Function
```

**EDIT**

The output of console.log(leXmlDoc) as the XML source string, I check and it is of type string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <Sections> 
<Section>
    <TheGreeting>Hello</TheGreeting>
    <ThePlanet>World</ThePlanet>
    <Puncuation>!</Puncuation>      
</Section>
</Sections>
```

Here is the out put as a Dom Document, I check using console.log($.isXmlDoc(leXmlDoc)) and the result is true, typeOf is an object and I created the leXMLDoc by this bit of code where theXmlFile is the XML source string from above:

```
var domParser = new DOMParser();
var XmlDOM = domParser.parseFromString(theXmlFile, "application/xml");
sendToServer(XmlDOM);
```

The output of console.log(leXmlDoc) as a dom Document is this

```
 #document
 <Sections> 
<Section>
    <TheGreeting>Hello</TheGreeting>
    <ThePlanet>World</ThePlanet>
    <Puncuation>!</Puncuation>      
</Section>
</Sections>
```

I hope this helps.

**UPDATE 1**

When I decided to console.log the xhr like this

```
   error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(ajaxOptions);
        console.log(thrownError);
    }
```

and open up the object I get an error that says

```
responseText: "System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: xml 
↵   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
↵   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
↵"
```

So it seems that the format is worng. Yet when I go directly to the webservice by navigating to like this

```
http://localhost:52530/WebServices/TransferXmlData.asmx/
```

And manually invoke the webservice with the output of console.log(leXmlDoc (Source string)), and then  copying and pasting it works fine.

Comment: So then are you having the "there is a problem sending the XML" in you js console, right?

Comment: Oh, you are having a problem sending XML not receiving it? Sorry, I misread your question, what is the error message?

Comment: @RobertRozas Yes, and it's a 500 internal server error.

Comment: @KarlAnderson plz see my comment above.

Comment: @KarlAnderson Now that you mention it I am not sure. I am mostly positive that I am having trouble sending the XML, since my webservice is very simple and just returns w/e is sent. And when I change the data I am sending from XML to JSON it works fine.

Comment: Please post the content of console.log(leXmlDoc)

Comment: @RobertRozas I edited my thread to contain the out put of  console.log(leXmlDoc).

Comment: @RobertRozas hey your answer is gone? This is the second time today that somebody's answer disappear.

Comment: 500 error can mean a lot of things. It would be preferable that you debug the script in e.g. Developer Tools. There's a possibility that your response is too large for the data type you're trying to store it in, especially since you say that calling the web method directly works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, I setup a server side client for using the ASMX webservice. Then using Fiddler inspected the SOAP packet it sent to the ASMX webserivce. This was the exact XML that I needed to send via  $.ajax call.